# How to find if a string contains all the characters of a string for live searching in Swift?

Tags: swift, livesearch

I'm trying to implement search inside my app that I'm making. I have an array that I'm trying to search and I find this code online:

```
 func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
        filteredCandies = candies.filter({( candy : Candies) -> Bool in
        if         candy.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) == true  {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The issue is that the database that I'm trying to implement search on has text that is all scrambled because it was supposed to shortened. How can I make it so that the search will check if all the letters are there instead of searching exactly the right name. Example of object from database (USDA): CRAB, DUNGINESS, RAW
If you have an answer, please make it fast enough for live searching. Non live searching makes searching terrible (at least for me)!

I'm using Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7

Comment: Why is it scrambled and what kind of user search looks for matching characters in any order?

Comment: The database was written by the USDA.

Answer (score 1):

As an improvement to [@appzYourLife's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38937803/2976878), you could do this with a native Swift [`Set`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Set/), as a counted set isn't necessarily needed in this case. This will save having to `map(_:)` over the characters of each name and bridging them to Objective-C. You can now just use a set of [`Character`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Character/)s, as they're [`Hashable`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/Hashable/).

For example:

```
struct Candy {
    let name: String
}

let candies = [Candy(name: "CRAB"), Candy(name: "DUNGINESS"), Candy(name: "RAW")]    
var filteredCandies = [Candy]()

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    let searchCharacters = Set(searchText.lowercaseString.characters)
    filteredCandies = candies.filter {Set($0.name.lowercaseString.characters).isSupersetOf(searchCharacters)}
    tableView.reloadData()
}

filterContentForSearchText("RA")
print(filteredCandies) // [Candy(name: "CRAB"), Candy(name: "RAW")]

filterContentForSearchText("ED")
print(filteredCandies) // Candy(name: "DUNGINESS")]
```

Also depending on whether you can identify this as a performance bottleneck (you should do some profiling first) – you could potentially optimise the above further by caching the sets containing the characters of your 'candy' names, saving from having to recreate them at each search (although you'll have to ensure that they're updated if you update your `candies` data).

When you come to search, you can then use [`zip(_:_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/func/zip/) and [`flatMap(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/#func--flatmap-t_-self-generator-element-throws-t) in order to filter out the corresponding candies.

```
let candies = [Candy(name: "CRAB"), Candy(name: "DUNGINESS"), Candy(name: "RAW")]

// cached sets of (lowercased) candy name characters
let candyNameCharacterSets = candies.map {Set($0.name.lowercaseString.characters)}

var filteredCandies = [Candy]()

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    let searchCharacters = Set(searchText.lowercaseString.characters)
    filteredCandies = zip(candyNameCharacterSets, candies).flatMap {$0.isSupersetOf(searchCharacters) ? $1 : nil}
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all a block of code like this

```
if someCondition == true {
   return true
} else {
   return false
}
```

can also be written this ways

```
return someCondition
```

right? :)

### Refactoring

So your original code would look like this

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    filteredCandies = candies.filter { $0.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

### Scrambled search

Now, given a string A, your want to know if another string B contains all the character of A right?

For this we need CountedSet which is available from Swift 3. Since you are using Swift 2.2 we'll use the old NSCountedSet but some bridging to Objective-C is needed.

Here's the code.

```
struct Candy {
    let name: String
}


let candies = [Candy]()
var filteredCandies = [Candy]()

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {

    let keywordChars = NSCountedSet(array:Array(searchText.lowercaseString.characters).map { String($0) })

    filteredCandies = candies.filter {
        let candyChars = NSCountedSet(array:Array($0.name.lowercaseString.characters).map { String($0) }) as Set<NSObject>
        return keywordChars.isSubsetOfSet(candyChars)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** code update :

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
  filteredCandies = candies.filter { candy in
    return candy.name.localizedLowercase.contains(searchText.lowercased())
  }

  tableView.reloadData()
}
```